# Expose fileds to views using hook_data

Tags: views, entities, hooks

```
.module file

/**
* Implements hook_views_api().
*/
function core_sms_views_api() {
    watchdog("test","<pre>".print_r('imhere',TRUE)."</pre>");
  return array("version" => "3.0");
}

.views.inc

<?php
/**
* Implements hook_views_data().
*/
function core_sms_views_data() {
  $data['core_sms_details']['table']['group'] = t('core_sms_details table');
  $data['core_sms_details']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'date', // This is the identifier field for the view.
    'title' => t('Core SMS details date'),
    'help' => t('Core_sms_details contains sent and failed sms counts on datewise.'),
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  // sent count field.
  $data['core_sms_details']['sent_count'] = array(
    'title' => t('Sent count'),
    'help' => t('Sent count field.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );

  // failed count field.
  $data['core_sms_details']['failed_count'] = array(
    'title' => t('failed count'),
    'help' => t('failed count field.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );
  return $data;
}
```

Thats the code i am using to expose the fields to views but i am not able to see in views add fields. what i am doing wrong. 
just to check i put watchdogs in both functions and the watchdogs are geting display.. please help.